# Digital to Analog converter with DAC5311, Any suggestion?

Tags: digital-analog-conversion

I made my DAC code with DAC5311 and Arduino Uno.
I think it has no problem, but it doesn't work well. Just print 0.(I use an oscilloscope.)
I don't know where has the problem. Please give me any suggestion.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pin_CS 10
#define pin_MOSI 11 
#define pin_SCLK 13
#define max_VOLT 5

void setVoltage(float voltage){
  if (voltage < 0) voltage = 0;
  if (voltage > max_VOLT) voltage = max_VOLT;
  uint16_t temp = int(voltage * pow(2, 8) / max_VOLT);
  temp = temp << 6;
  uint8_t upper = temp >> 8;
  uint8_t lower = (temp & 0xff);
  digitalWrite(pin_CS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(upper);
  SPI.transfer(lower);
  digitalWrite(pin_CS, HIGH); 
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin_CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_MOSI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_SCLK, OUTPUT);              
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  digitalWrite(pin_CS, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  setVoltage(5);
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: a statement, `it doesn't work well`, has no meaning  ... `I use an oscilloscope` is also meaningless ... please explain what you expected to happen, what actually happened and what you did with the oscilloscope

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English. So it might be not clear. The point is that I want to set  voltage 5, but the output of DAC5311 is zero. And I check the output with oscilloscope.

Comment: now, that is clear ... please edit your question ... your english is just fine ... is your oscilloscope functioning correctly and are the controls set correctly? ... double check the output using a voltmeter

Answer (score 3):

Classical +/- 1 problem

If you do this calculation by hand `uint16_t temp = int(voltage * pow(2, 8) / max_VOLT);`
you will get `temp=256` and this is a value you can not convert with a 8 bit DAC.

Try `uint16_t temp = int(voltage * (pow(2, 8)-1) / max_VOLT);` instead.

(or event better for a µC `uint16_t temp = (uint16_t) (voltage * (255 / max_VOLT));`)

Comment: I revised it, but it was not still working. ㅜㅜ

Comment: So please try `SPI_MODE1` or `SPI_MODE3`
(the device expects the valid bit on the falling clock phase)